# Formulation of Biomass reaction for metabolic model

Tags: bioinformatics, biotechnology, literature

What are some good review articles that could help me develop basic knowledge regarding biomass equation formulation? 
I read this paper titled [biomass objective function](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2912156/), but it only gives a general idea, and I'd like to learn more about the specifics of the process.

Comment: Please have a look at the [tag wiki for reference-request](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info). Your question should have all the details outlined in there. There is a book called [Metabolic Engineering by Stephanopaulos et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780126662603). That should give you some basic knowledge.

Comment: What precisely do you want to know? Are you interested in biomass composition for a particular cell type / experiment, or in the math involved? The paper you cite provides a good starting point for biotechnology applications I think. But for most organisms, there is little experimental data available on biomass composition.